# Swift3.2 - How to assign 2 classes to same View Controller?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I want to assign 2 classes to one view Controller , i used same ui many Times if i can assign 2 classes for one view controller it wil be great and faster

Comment: Do you mean 2 instances of the same view controller?

Comment: why but ? create another viewcontroller for other class! (you can just copy whole viewcontroller) from storyboard or xib!

Comment: You can not set two view controller in save design in storyboard , You have two options as @Lion said copy paste whole screen either manage same class for multiple screens (Not recommended ) with some boolean

Comment: @Lion isn't make the app slower ??

Comment: nop! It will not make app slow!

Comment: @JonSnow Thank You too

Comment: how about just taking advantages of OOP and using _inheritance_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @Lion and @Jon Snow above just copy and paste the whole screen. You won't notice any performance loss from doing this and will achieve exactly what you would like it to.